# C# Impersonate Error to Connect SQL Server

Tags: c#, connection, impersonation, trust

After the last update on Windows 7, my Windows application connection database doesn't work anymore.

I use "Impersonate" to change the user logon and than use trusted connection, but after the Windows update, my connection method returns the message:

> *The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.*

Impersonate:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx

Trust Connection:

```
"Initial Catalog=Aspect;Integrated Security=SSPI;Data Source=Server1,1433;Database=DWork;User Id=svc-test;Password=123456;"
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What is the rest of the exception detail? Also, do not supply `User Id` and `Password` if you intend to use integrated security. Likewise, do not use integrated security if you are using a sql login. Pick one.

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: I changed the connection to: Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;

Comment: The innerException Message: Catastrophic failure (excption from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF)

Comment: I belive the error start after windows update: KB4344167

Comment: Consider isolating the problem by writing a toy console app that does nothing but attempt to open a connection with that connection string.

Comment: I made this isolating: